# Symmetric Matrix in Eigen C++

Tags: matrix, c++, eigen

I am aware of a symmetric matrix type in uBLAS as ublas::symmetric_matrix matrix. Is there an equivalent for this in Eigen library that can be used to construct one or do we need to explicitly check if a matrix is symmetric or not which could be a time expensive solution (O(n^2)). Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: For now, I did something like this

if (m.selfadjointView<Upper>() == m.selfadjointView<Lower>()) {}
else {}

If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Typically, if you need a symmetric matrix you just completely ignore the upper or lower triangle of the matrix. You can fill the non-referenced triangle with NaNs for all you care. If you want to use a linear algebra routine that does not support implicitly symmetric matrices, then you would fill the other triangle like so: `m = m.selfadjointView<Lower>();`